# ArcMap adds decimal to string conversion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0

ArcMap dropped the leading zero from the census block ID for California. When I added a new text field, GEOID, in the field calculator with the formula,

```
GEOID = "0" + str(!BLOCK_2020!)
```

ArcMap created the text field but populated it with one decimal place -- for example, 060014001001001.0.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Insert int( before BLOCK

Comment: Your title is misleading, since ArcMap didn't format the string -- Python did.

Answer (score 4):

Always use `str.format()` to control formatting (vice a `str` cast), then you can do something like:

```py
geoid = "{:015d}".format(long(!block_2020!))
```

Under Python3 (ArcGIS Pro) that "long" becomes "int":

```py
geoid = "{:015d}".format(int(!block_2020!))
```